# Identify Max Value if exist in group - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm Trying Identify max value in group.

I was trying with Max and Min Function.
But i can't get max, only if there is a greater one, if they are all the same, I do not want to do anything.

**Expected Result:**
*Example 1*

```
OWNER   ACCOUNT   MONEY  isMAX
Admin   account1  1000   YES  
Admin   account2  500    NO
Admin   account3  300    NO
```

**Expected Result:**
*Example 2*

```
OWNER   ACCOUNT   MONEY  isMAX
Admin   account1  500     
Admin   account2  500    
Admin   account3  500
```

**Expected Result:**
*Example 3*

```
OWNER   ACCOUNT   MONEY  isMAX
Admin   account1  500    YES  
Admin   account2  500    YES
Admin   account3  300    NO
```

I'm playing with MAX, MIN and CASE function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(money) over (partition by owner, account) = 
                  max(money) over (partition by owner, account)
             then NULL
             when money = max(money) over (partition by owner, account)
             then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end) as isMax
from t;
```

Comment: Small question Gordon, do you know the perf difference between `over partition by` and a simple `join max group by` ? I'm curious as I usually go straight on join with sub query and forgot a bit about over partition feature...

Comment: @Blag . . . In most databases, the window functions have better performance than `join` and `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3af8b2/4)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    t1.OWNER,
    t1.money,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.money = t2.ma AND t1.money > T2.mi
        THEN 'YES'
        WHEN t1.money < T2.ma
        THEN 'NO'
        ELSE ''
    END AS isMAX
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT OWNER, max(money) ma, min(money) mi
        FROM t
        GROUP BY OWNER
    ) t2
    ON t1.OWNER = t2.OWNER

order by owner, ismax desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3af8b2/4/0)**:

```
|  OWNER | MONEY |  ISMAX |
|--------|-------|--------|
| Admin1 |  1000 |    YES |
| Admin1 |   500 |     NO |
| Admin1 |   500 |     NO |
| Admin2 |   500 | (null) |
| Admin2 |   500 | (null) |
| Admin2 |   500 | (null) |
| Admin3 |   500 |    YES |
| Admin3 |   500 |    YES |
| Admin3 |   300 |     NO |
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I love you :D
It works perfectly. ^_^